# Why in PyQt5 mp3 file loop isn't working?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I make an application which will ring an mp3 for 100 times. But it works only for 1 time. Why this is happening?

Here is the code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys


class AlarmWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, alarmName, alarmTime, alarmTone):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle = alarmName
        self.top, self.left = 100, 50
        self.width, self.height = 600, 350
        self.setFixedWidth(600)
        self.setFixedHeight(350)
        self.icon = "icons\\alarm.ico"
  
        self.url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(alarmTone)
        self.content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.play()
        self.show()

    def play(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.player.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AlarmWindow("Name", "7:55 PM", "basic.mp3")
    app.exec()
```

Comment: From what the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html) looks like, the player media is state sensitive. The [playlist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplaylist.html#playbackMode-prop) in `self.content` has a `next()` function. Likely you want to call that instead (playlist with a length of 1 should then restart the only title again).

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks. But in case of dynamic files i.e. user definded ringtone, how can I know than when I have to call the stop function?

Comment: @starturtle thanks but can you elaborate please? I'm very beginner in PyQt5.

Comment: @Carcigenicate this is the problem for me too! I never use this library before :(

Comment: @DebtanuGupta answer by @mkrieger1 looks better. I'm talking about `self.player.currentMedia().playlist().next()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self.player.play()` does not block until the mp3 has finished playing. Calling it 100 times in a row will do nothing while it is still playing.

You could use the [`stateChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#stateChanged) signal to be notified when the player has finished playing, and then start it again with a callback.

It should work something like this:

```
def play(self):
    played = 0

    def restart(state):
        nonlocal played
        if state != QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            return
        if played == 100:
            return
        played += 1
        self.player.play()

    self.player.stateChanged.connect(restart)
    self.player.play()
```